# Adonis JS - Access Model's custom method

Tags: adonis.js

I've added a custom method called `customMethod` to a model, like so:

```
class Prize extends Model {

  customMethod(){

    return 'test'

  }

}
```

When I use find to get a prize by primary key I can call this method no problem

```
    const prize = await Prize.find(1);

    return prize.customMethod();
    //returns 'test'
```

but when if I get a prize any other way, through a relationship or by querying by a field, I can't access this method.

```
   const countrysPrizes = await country.prizes().fetch();

    for (const key in countrysPrizes) {
      if (countrysPrizes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const prize = countrysPrizes[key];

        return prize.customMethod();
        //returns 500 - prize.customMethod is not a function
      }
    }
```

How can I access this method while iterating through multiple of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to use `<fetched_object>.rows` because of `VanillaSerializer`**

#### Example code :

```js
  const user = await User.find(1);
  const posts = await user.posts().fetch();

  posts.rows.forEach(post=> { // use .rows
    console.info(post.customMethod()); // Your custom method
  });
```

*I've had trouble using the basic `foreach` loop. So I used `.foreach()`*

#### An output example with `fetch()` :

[image: AdonisJS VanillaSerializer - Output example]